# Directive to automatically set placeholders

Tags: angular

I have many forms where all my fields are like this:

```
<div class="dx-field">
                            <div class="dx-field-label">Company name</div>
                            <div class="dx-field-value">
                                <dx-text-box [(value)]="Entity.CompanyName" placeholder="Company name">

                                </dx-text-box>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I would like to make a directive that I can apply to the dx-text-box (3rd part component) to set the placeholder property to the content of dx-field-label, so that I do not have to specify everything twice
Can this be acheived, the Angular way?

Comment: This questions feels like you are asking people to write the directive for you. Update the question to show what you've tried and we'll help you get it working, but we won't do the work for you.

Comment: I'm not even sure where to start here. I mean I know how to make directives that add some kind of property to the component itself, but I have no idea how to traverse up the tree here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a template reference in the HTML to read the text content.

```
<div class="dx-field">
     <div class="dx-field-label" #label>Company name</div>
     <div class="dx-field-value">
        <dx-text-box [(value)]="Entity.CompanyName" [placeholder]="label.textContent">
        </dx-text-box>
     </div>
</div>
```

A directive can not update the `@Input()` binding on `<dx-text-box>` externally (not in an easy way to understand at least), but you can write a function that can fetch the value. Here is an example of passing a template reference to a component function.

```
<div class="dx-field">
     <div class="dx-field-label">Company name</div>
     <div class="dx-field-value">
        <dx-text-box [(value)]="Entity.CompanyName" #inputRef [placeholder]="getLabel(inputRef)">
        </dx-text-box>
     </div>
</div>

public getLabel(inputRef: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>) {
    const parent = inputRef.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement;
    const label = parent.querySelector('.dx-field-label');
    return label && label.textContent;
}
```

The third approach is to create a new component that renders both the label and `<dx-text-box>` and takes the label as an `@Input()` binding. You'll have to add two-way binding to forward changes in the value.

If `<dx-text-box>` is a reactive form control, then you'll have to Google how to have the new component provide the FormControl to child elements. I forget how to do it but you'll know if you need it, because the reactive form will show an error in the console output.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the 3rd approach

Answer (score -1):

You have to use one-way binding.

In your HTML:

```
<div class="dx-field-label">{{companyName}}</div>
<dx-text-box [(value)]="Entity.CompanyName" placeholder={{companyName}}>
```

In your ts file:

```
let companyName = "Company Name";
```

Comment: This is possible but its not what I am looking for. I want to keep my template in the template file and just make the definition shorter, not to define a variable for each name in the component

Comment: I'm not sure if I do understand. Could you please update your post with more details?